# Simulate keyboard press

Tags: java, keyboard

Is there any other way to simulate keyboard presses except Robot?
Could you give some code examples?

Or perhabs you could give me some advice with Robot(). I'm trying to simulate keyboard presses due the timer end. Its works ok with Robot() unless it types in notepad or so. BUT I want to write it inside the game (in-game chat).
Well, it types, but after message is typed in chat I can't use keyboard. It gets like disabled.

I need these buttons to be typed:

```
    private int drake60[] =
        {
                KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,
                KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.VK_R, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_K, KeyEvent.VK_E,
                KeyEvent.VK_SPACE,
                KeyEvent.VK_I, KeyEvent.VK_N,
                KeyEvent.VK_SPACE,
                KeyEvent.VK_6, KeyEvent.VK_0,
                KeyEvent.VK_SPACE,
                KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.VK_E, KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.VK_O, KeyEvent.VK_N, KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.VK_S,
                KeyEvent.VK_ENTER
        };
```

And this is how it was made:

```
    public void drake60(){
    try{
        robot = new Robot();
        for (int i = 0; i < drake60.length; i++)
        {
            robot.keyPress(drake60[i]);
        }
    } catch (AWTException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

^This works but keyboard doesn't respond after (only in-game).

Comment: Please post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `KeyListener`in java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html